# How do I get Target Q-values in Bipedalwalker-v3 in openai-gym, reinforcement learning?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am new to reinforcement learning and I was trying to solve the *BipedalWalker-v3* using **Deep Q learning**. However I found out that the `env.action_space.sample() = numpy array with 4 elements` and I am not sure how to add `rewards` and multiply it by the `(1-done_list)`, I have tried copying my code from the [**LunarLander**](https://github.com/Astrojigs/LunarLander-Agent/blob/main/main.py) project.

In the case of Lunar lander the `env.action_space.sample() = integer`.

Here is my method to update the 'Lunar lander' model:

```
def update_model(self):
        random_sample = random.sample(self.replay_buffer, self.batch_size)
        
        states, actions, rewards, next_states, done_list = self.get_attributes_from_sample(random_sample)
        # How do I fix the below target for BipedalWalker
        targets = rewards + self.gamma * (np.max(self.model.predict_on_batch(next_states), axis=1)) * (1 - done_list)
        
        target_vec = self.model.predict_on_batch(states) # shape = (64, 4)
        indexes = np.array([i for i in range(self.batch_size)])
        target_vec[[indexes], [actions]] = targets

        self.model.fit(states, target_vec, epochs=1, verbose=0)
```

This worked really well in the LunarLander environment.

I need to implement this in the **BiPedalWalker** project. It can be found here: [link](https://github.com/Astrojigs/Bipedal-walker/blob/main/main.py)

However the model isn't producing any good results even after 1000 episodes.

Here is the same method for *BipedalWalker*:

```
   def update_model(self):
        # replay_buffer size Check
        if len(self.replay_buffer) < self.batch_size or self.counter != 0:
            return

        # Early Stopping
        if np.mean(self.rewards_list[-10:]) > 180:
            return

        # take a random sample:
        random_sample = random.sample(self.replay_buffer, self.batch_size)
        # Extract the attributes from sample
        states, actions, rewards, next_states, done_list = self.get_attributes_from_sample(random_sample)
        targets = np.tile(rewards, (self.num_action_space, 1)).T + np.multiply(np.tile((1 - done_list), (self.action_space.sample().size, 1)).T, np.multiply(self.gamma, self.model.predict_on_batch(next_states)))
        # print(targets.shape) = (64,)
        target_vec = self.model.predict_on_batch(states) # shape = (64, 4)
        indexes = np.array([i for i in range(self.batch_size)])
        target_vec = targets

        self.model.fit(states, target_vec, epochs=1, verbose=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the DQN algorithm to solve a continuous action space environment (like the bipedal walker v3) is a bad idea because the DQN algorithm relies on an iterative optimization process of the pair (state, action). I recommend changing to another algorithm like TD3, SAC or PPO.

Comment: I see. I will have to research a bit more on these policies. Thanks!